# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, sql-server, casting, integer, short

In my project I have an Enum like this :

```
public enum MyEnum {

FIRST(1),

SECOND(2);

private int value;

private MyEnum(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public static MyEnum fromValue(int value) {
    for (MyEnum e : MyEnum.values()) {
        if (e.getValue() == value) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I have this code :

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
// Fill my Map with data from database
myMap = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(qry, paramsMap);

***if (Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values())
                .contains(MyEnum.fromValue((int) 
                myMap.get("myKey")) )))*** {
    // Do something
    }
```

I get the Exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer** on this line : **if (Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values())
            .contains(MyEnum.fromValue((int)myMap.get("myKey")) )))
```

***myMap*** is filled with data from database, knowing that it is an SQL Server Database and that the ***myKey*** returned from database is of type ***tinyint*** in the database.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: By the way, `EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class)` is far more efficient (and easier to read) than Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()).  See [the  documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll try that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer

Here `myMap.get("myKey")` returns a `Short` instance but the returned declared object is `Object` as the map is declared `Map<String, Object>`.

It is as if you had written :

```
Object myValue = myMap.get("myKey")
```

Then you pass this `Short` object declared as `Object` to `MyEnum.fromValue()` that has as parameter an `int`.

```
MyEnum.fromValue((int)myValue));
```

The compiler tries so to cast the object to an `Integer`.
But it is not an `Integer` but a `Short`.
So the cast fails.

To solve your problem, you should first check the instance of your object.
If the object is not an instance of `Short`, you should throw an exception or ignore the value.
If it is, you should cast from `Object` to `Short` and pass this `Short` to `fromValue()` that will be automatically unboxed to `short` :

```
   Object myValue =  myMap.get("myKey");
   if (!(myValue instanceof Short)){          
      throw new YourRuntimeException("A Short is expected but get a " + myValue.getClass());
      // or ignore the value
   }

   if (Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values())
              .contains(MyEnum.fromValue(((short) myValue)) {
           ....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it works. However I've written this little part of code which works : Short i = new Short((short) 1);
        int j = (int) i;
        System.out.println(i);   . It's the same thing and it works in this case, can you please tell me why ? I'm just trying to understand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason is simple. Here `int j = (int) i;` the compiler unboxes `i` value from `Short` to `short` and then does a widening conversion from `short` to `int`.   Besides the cast is useless for widening conversion. `int j =  i;` is enough. It is required only for narrowing conversion.
In your actual code, the `Short` instance is declared as `Object`. So the compiler doesn't try to unbox it but do directly a cast to the target cast. I edited to explain it and provide a still more effective solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Here :

```java
(int)myMap.get("myKey")
```

I guess that the get method returned a reference to a Short object, which can't be cast to Integer, since short doesn't inherit from Integer.

What you can do is casting to Short, then call the [intValue method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#intValue--), like this :

```java
((Short)myMap.get("myKey")).intValue()
```

Which will return a integer value

Comment: thanks, it worked. But I had to choose the cleanest solution

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution from my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
(int)(short)myMap.get("myKey")
```